# Using Previouspage, why do i get "the object is null before calling a method..." message while using try...catch?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have used `PreviousPage` property and it always worked fine passing data from one page to another. Recently, I tried to add error handling into my code using try...catch method saving the exception in a text file. Using this method, I am getting the following exception on a line like `TitleResultlbl.Text = PreviousPage.TitleProp` while the program runs fine as before.

Exception.message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why do I get this exception?

I am using vb.net and all references in pages are correct. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Either TitleResultlbl or PreviousPage is null. But without showing the code, it would be impossible to speculate as to which is the cause. Please post the code in question.

Comment: It is a very long lines of code and as I said earlier, it was working fine before. Just imagine there is a try...catch around the given line which causes the Catch to be invoked and I use a call to a class to write the exception into a text file. This class also works perfectly and tested before.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to say? Without seeing the code, we can't really help you. Whether or not it worked before is irrelevant. Obviously it's not working now.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is called for the first page, there will be no previous page

```
If PreviousPage Is Nothing Then
    TitleResultlbl.Text = ""
Else
    TitleResultlbl.Text = PreviousPage.TitleProp
End If
```

Comment: I thought of using the same code but it is combersome to have it for about 20 values passed from the previous page! I am going to try it anyway for a few fields but it does not make sense because even if the PreviousPage is nothing, why do i get the previous page values?

Comment: The question is not whether it is cumbersome or not but whether `PreviousPage` is `Nothing` or not.

Comment: As I expected having your piece of code, it does not give me exception on that line but i have a empty string for the TitleResultlbl in the second page:( The question is why with the single line of code, I get the exception message while the values are passed from the previous page perfectly?

Comment: Code: '<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/MyFolder/Subfolder/Cont_Add.aspx" %> ' at the top of the second page (Cont_Add2.aspx). I have 'Public ReadOnly Property TitleProp() As String
        Get
            Return TitleDDL.SelectedItem.Text
        End Get
    End Property'

Comment: Sorry I press Return key and it submits the comment before I am done. The last line of code was from the first page (Cont_Add.aspx.vb). I am wondering if the PreviousPage is Nothing, why do I still get the values if I don't use your code.

Comment: With the single line of code an exception is thrown and no new text is assigned to the label. Therefore it keeps its previous value.

Comment: I am sorry, Olivier. I am trying to understand your comment. Based on what you said, with 'TitleResultlbl.Text = PreviousPage.TitleProp' and try...catch in the code, where does the previous value is coming from while the PreviousPage is actually nothing?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing your code. But if `PreviousPage` is `Nothing` the line `TitleResultlbl.Text = PreviousPage.TitleProp` will not assign any text to the label and the label will contain the same text as it contained before this line was executed. You should not guess. Instead debug your code! Visual Studio has a debugger!

Comment: Thanks for your help, Olivier. I know how to use VS debugger a little and I used it. It was giving me the exact exception message and nothing more. Maybe I have to give up using try..catch and error handling for the page because without them, I get the results I want except no error handling method!

Comment: When the executions stops at a breakpoints you can inspect the values of the variables. This more than just an exception message. Set the breakpoint before the faulty line is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be the postback issue on the second page. In fact, when I was clicking on a final approval button on the second page, its Page_Load sub was being called again and there wasn't any checking like "If Not IsPostBack" before the lines accessing values from the first page inside that sub. It caused the 'PreviousPage.TitleProp' to be run again where it couldn't find the PreviousPage anymore causing the exception! I added the above IF clause around the codes in Page_Load sub and it worked fine.